# Query: generated start_date and end_date where it isn't exist in the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

i want to ask something, so i have a table A that have start_date and end_date column to store the data when there is a failure happened, it look like this

| rows | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "2021-08-01 00:04:00" | "2021-08-01 02:54:00" |
| 2 | "2021-08-01 04:52:00" | "2021-08-01 05:32:00" |

And what i want to do is to have a query so that the response will come out like this (for example i want to get the data of 1 August 2021), it fill a row between start_date and end_date that doesn't exist in table and fill type as *normal* and *otherwise* fill it as  *failure*

| rows | start_date | end_date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "2021-08-01 00:00:00" | "2021-08-01 00:03:00" | normal |
| 2 | "2021-08-01 00:04:00" | "2021-08-01 02:54:00" | failure |
| 3 | "2021-08-01 02:55:00" | "2021-08-01 04:51:00" | normal |
| 4 | "2021-08-01 04:52:00" | "2021-08-01 05:32:00" | failure |
| 5 | "2021-08-01 05:53:00" | "2021-08-01 23:59:00" | normal |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the "normal" rows in another table or are you wanting them to be derived somehow?

Comment: @Hambone don't have the table for the normal one, only have the table for the failure. I want the query to do the job somehow, any idea?

Comment: I think so...  except for one thing.  It looks like it's filling in the "gaps," but there are still gaps.  For example between 3:00 AM and 4:00 AM -- unaccounted for.  Is there a pattern to the gaps between the failures and the normal times?

Comment: @Hambone yeah it's like filling in the "gaps" with a given input time(?), the pattern is only look at the record at table A(?), so about the time between 3 AM and 4 AM are accounted to the rows number 3, from datetime 02:55 to 04:51 which fills it as a normal.

Comment: When you supply a sample data (Chapeau for that ), you would like to **reduce** the chance for mistakes, not increase it.  `00:04:00`, `02:54:00` & `04:52:00` doesn't seem like a great choice...

Comment: Is this report always looks on a single day?

Comment: Does the row with the minimum start_date guaranteed to have rows = 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create dates between and unpivot them using `union all`. Then we add the last line and do the same.

```
with t2 as (
            select *,'failure' as type 
            from   t

  
union all 

  
            select  rows
                   ,coalesce(lag(end_date) over(order by end_date) + interval '1 minute', date_trunc('hour', start_date)) as start_date
                   ,start_date + interval '-1 minute' as end_date
                   ,'normal'
            from   t

  
union all

  
            select  max(rows) 
                   ,max(end_date) + interval '1 minute'
                   ,date_trunc('day', max(end_date)) + interval '1 day -1 minute'
                   ,'normal'
            from    t

order by rows, start_date
           )

select  row_number() over(order by start_date) as rows
       ,start_date
       ,end_date
       ,type
from    t2
```

| rows | start_date | end_date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 2021-08-01 00:03:00 | normal |
| 2 | 2021-08-01 00:04:00 | 2021-08-01 02:54:00 | failure |
| 3 | 2021-08-01 02:55:00 | 2021-08-01 04:51:00 | normal |
| 4 | 2021-08-01 04:52:00 | 2021-08-01 05:32:00 | failure |
| 5 | 2021-08-01 05:33:00 | 2021-08-01 23:59:00 | normal |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/48dCaOIm)

Answer (score 2):

Good answer from DannySlor...  if you want something really easy to maintain and tweak (and scale), you can also wrap it in a function:

```
create or replace function fill_day(snapshot_date date)
returns table (xrows integer, xstart_date timestamp, xend_date timestamp, xtype text)
language plpgsql
as
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    rw record;
    last_date timestamp := snapshot_date;
  BEGIN
    xrows := 1;

    for rw in select *
              from table_a a
              where a.start_date::date = snapshot_date
              order by rows
    loop
      xstart_date := last_date;
      xend_date := rw.start_date - interval '1 minute';
      xtype := 'normal';
      return next;
      xrows := xrows + 1;

      xstart_date := rw.start_date;
      xend_date := rw.end_date;
      xtype := 'failure';
      return next;
      xrows := xrows + 1;

      last_date = rw.end_date + interval '1 minute';
    end loop;

    xstart_date := last_date;
    xend_date := snapshot_date + interval '1 day - 1 minute';
    xtype := 'normal';
    return next;
  END;
$BODY$
```

Here's how you would execute it:

```
select * from fill_day('2021-08-01')
```